# MVC 5 pass model from view to controller using actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass data collected in my view to be passed to my controller as model. (cause my variables are too much I am just showing few )

Here is my Model :

```
 public class Arama
    {
        public string nereden { get; set; }
        public int neredenTip { get; set; }

        public string nereye { get; set; }
        public int nereyeTip { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller :

```
public ActionResult UcakArama(Arama arama)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Ukn", "U", arama);
        }
```

and here is my view :

```
 @model  kyWeb.Models.Arama
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/AramaEkran")
       <li class="dyas_li">
          <div id="nereden">
            <span class="dyas_ttl">3.Çocuk</span>
               <div class="smll2-select">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.nereden, new SelectList(new int[] { 2, 3, 4}, 2), new { tabindex = "1", id = "yds" })

                </div>
             </div>
          </li>
<li class="dyas_li">
          <div id="nereye">
            <span class="dyas_ttl">3.Çocuk</span>
               <div class="smll2-select">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.nereye, new SelectList(new int[] { 2, 3, 4}, 2), new { tabindex = "1", id = "yds" })

                </div>
             </div>
          </li>
               @Html.ActionLink("ARA", "ucakarama", new { arama = this.Model })
```

When I debug , I see that the model is turning null. 
 I want to get the values from html and pass it into my controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `@Html.ActionLink` because that produces a `GET` request. You need to `POST` to your controller action by enclosing your properties in a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//properties go here
<li class="dyas_li">
    <div id="nereden">
    <span class="dyas_ttl">3.Çocuk</span>
        <div class="smll2-select">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.nereden, new SelectList(new int[] { 2, 3, 4}, 2), new { tabindex = "1", id = "yds" })
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
//...etc
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

Comment: How does one access the model when doing it like this? I mean in the controller.

Comment: @inifus `[HttpPost]public ActionResult UcakArama(Arama arama)` MVC will bind the properties in the form to the parameter of the method.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show", 
                 "Show", 
                 null, 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", 
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                 UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id", 
                 OnComplete = "your_js_function();" })
```

@Ajax.ActionLink requires jQuery AJAX Unobtrusive library. You can download it via nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

Then add this code to your View:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Here's the [MSDN documentation for Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx)